# Sitecore 9.1 Prerequisites check: No registration found for extension 'if' of type 'ConfigFunction' exception

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I have successfully installed **Sitecore 9.1** (**XM** topology) locally (Windows 10). But when I tried to install the same instance on Test environment (Windows Server 2016) I  have encountered the following issue when I run the prerequisites check:

[image]

```
WARNING: Validation failed for parameter 'TempLocation' = 'SIF-Default'. Exception: Exception calling "Validate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to
parse [TestPath(variable('Temp.Location'))] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse
[if(variable('Test.Temp.Location'),Environment('Temp'),parameter('TempLocation'))] - No registration found for extension 'if' of type 'ConfigFunction'."".
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Parameters validation has failed.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\Prerequisites.json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:00
Parameters validation has failed.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:474 char:21
+                     throw "Parameters validation has failed."
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Parameters validation has failed.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Parameters validation has failed.
```

In my point of view the main reason of exception is "*No registration found for extension 'if' of type 'ConfigFunction'."".*". It looks like the **Invoke-IfConfigFunction** extension is not registered or is not available in context of variable validation. But I can successfully run this extension in PowerShell separately.

- Windows Server 2016;
- PowerShell version: 5.1;
- SIF Version: 2.0.0.

Does anybody have any idea why it happens?

Comment: Could you run `Get-SitecoreInstallExtension -Path c:\sc91\prerequisites.json` and see if the `Invoke-IfConfigFunction` is there? 

Not sure why it wouldn't be registered as its a built in function.

Have you edited the prerequisites.json file?

Comment: @RichardDzien Yes, Invoke-IfConfigFunction is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a work around to finish the installation. My answer doesn't explain why the issue happens but at least it helped me to finish what I was needed.

I added the `"if": "Invoke-IfConfigFunction"` line in the `Registration -> ConfigFunction` section to the `Prerequisites.json`:

```
"Register":{
        "Tasks":{
            "InstallModule": "Install-Module",
            "EnableWindowsOptionalFeature": "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature",
            "StartProcess" : "Start-Process",
            "WriteOutput": "Write-Output"
        },
        "ConfigFunction":{
            "GetModule": "Get-Module",
            "GetPackage" : "Get-Package",
            "GetItemPropertyValue" : "Get-ItemPropertyValue",
            "TestPath": "Test-Path",
            "if": "Invoke-IfConfigFunction"
        }
    },
```

It allowed me to run Prerequisites check and finish it successfully.

**P.S.** Then I faced the same exception during Sitecore installation process. Solution was similar: I added the following lines in the Registration section of `XM1-SingleDeveloper.json`:

```
  "ConfigFunction":{
        "if": "Invoke-IfConfigFunction"
    }
```

Finally, it looks like below:

```
"Register": {
        "Tasks": {
            "OutNull": "Out-Null"
        },
        "ConfigFunction":{
            "if": "Invoke-IfConfigFunction"
        }
    }
```

I would be much appreciated if somebody can explain why it happens.

Comment: This should not be necessary at all. Could you remove this from one if your files and then run it with -verbose. The output should have what is registered and when.

Comment: @RichardDzien I know that it should not be there at all. But I didn't find any other solution to continue installation. 
I have run the `Prerequisites` check again with `-verbose`. You can find a result by the url: https://github.com/ampach/Sitecore/blob/master/Shared/PS-Output.txt

Comment: I can't explain this... The If configfunction is being registered at line 41 of your log. There is no reason it shouldn't find it. The only explanation i can think of is that somehow either the configs or the module are corrupt in a non-obvious way. Or maybe some sort of UTF-8 thing? I do stress i am clutching at straws there. What happens if you re-install the module and try in a new session?

Comment: @RichardDzien I've tried to re-install SIF 2.0.0. I did it before I post question here... I tried to debug SIF, I think I tried everything... Only one unusual thing that there is a Turkish language installed in the same time with English. Everything else looks the same with my local where installation was successful.

Comment: @RichardDzien And also if it is the issue of UTF-8, I can't imagine how my work around helped :) There is nothing logical in this issue... Maybe a problem of only specific environment, maybe not... anyway, I will setup multi server Sitecore infrastructure soon and I will check if the issue there as well.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're using an incorrect version of prerequisites.json file from another package by accident?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, It happened due to the usage of the wrong SIF version. Refer to this for commands and version types - http://www.navavayas.com/blog/no-registration-found-for-extension-managekeystorage-of-type-task-sitecore-install/